# No output in console python

Tags: python, pycharm

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def imdb_spider():
   url = 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
   source_code = requests.get(url)
   plain_text = source_code.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
   for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'secondaryInfo' }):
       href = link.get('href')
       print(href)

imdb_spider()
```

I'm  trying to get links of all top  rated movies from imdb . I'm using pycharm . The code runs  for more than 30 mins but i'm not getting any print in my console.

Comment: where did you get `source_code` ? This code can't run. You should get error message.

Comment: There is an IMDB python library... http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net

Comment: where do you use `requests`? Did you forget to paste a line?

Comment: I forgot to add one line, I have added now. @RafaelMartins

Comment: You can use debug mode on line `print(href)` to see if is there anything to print in `href`.

Comment: I checked through debug mode , it is not going under that loop only. i don't know why it is unable to find class=SecondaryInfo  @Quba

Comment: I added one line                                                                                               t = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'secondaryInfo'}).__len__() and it is giving t as 0. It is unable to find class = secondaryInfo. Can you check that site and tell me which class i should take.

Comment: I checked with     t = soup.findAll('a', {'itemprop': 'url'}).__len__()
and it is running fine plus I;m getting outputs also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `{'class': 'secondaryInfo' }` is a parameter of `<span>` object.

So try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def imdb_spider():
    url = 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
    for td in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'titleColumn'}):
        href = td.find('a').get('href')
        print(href)


imdb_spider()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that there's an element with class `secondaryInfo` for every movie title, but that's not the `a` element. If you want to find that, you have to use a different selector. For example, the following selector will do the trick instead of using `soup.findAll()`.

`soup.select('td.titleColumn a')`